# ajax.actionlink updating divs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently I have a page with two columns, the left hand of which contains some links and the right hand one displays additional data based on what was clicked.

Currently I'm having difficulty getting the Ajax.ActionLink method to successfully update the right hand column.

Currently my page looks a bit like this:

```
<div id="lefthand">

@Ajax.ActionLink("Children", "ViewDetail", new { details = ViewBag.data }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "details" })

</div>

<div id="righthand">

<ul id="details">

</ul>

</div>
```

When I click on the link however, a new page is created - not a portion of the page I'm currently on (I'm creating a partial view).

I've used this sucessfully in another part of the site, but where the updated bit was within the same . Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file as a script reference.